# Lighttpd mod_accesslog not logging fastcgi requests

Tags: linux, debian, lighttpd, mod-fastcgi

I have recently installed a lighttpd for serving a python script via **mod_fastcgi**.  Everything works fine except that I don't get the requests handled by **mod_fastcgi** logged in the *access.log* file (requests on port 80 are logged though).
My lighttpd version is 1.4.28 on a Debian 6.0. I used the same working configuration a Ubuntu server 10.04 with lighttpd 1.4.26 and it worked.

Here is my config

lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules              = (
            "mod_access",
            "mod_alias",
            "mod_accesslog",
            "mod_compress",
)
server.document-root       = "/var/www/"
server.upload-dirs = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog            = "/home/log/lighttpd/error.log"
index-file.names           = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                               "index.htm", "default.htm",
                               "index.lighttpd.html" )
accesslog.filename         = "/home/log/lighttpd/access.log"
url.access-deny            = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )
server.pid-file            = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"

include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

conf-enabled/10-fastcgi.conf

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
fastcgi.server =    (
                        "/" =>
                         (
                           ( "min-procs" => 1,
                           "check-local" => "disable",
                           "host" => "127.0.0.1", # local
                           "port" => 3000
                          ),
                        )
                   )
```

Any idea ?